# Is it possible to export a sims 4 lot to a 3d model?

Tags: the-sims-4

I have a Sims 4 lot that I want to turn into a 3d model but I can't figure out how to. Looking it up yields no good results, and most of them just show you how to export your lot to a file. Is it possible to export it as a 3d model instead? This includes the build that I did on the lot.